# How to foreach or showing data JSON to view Codeigniter 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Here I'm a newbie for JSON, the question??, How to **foreach** data JSON **(in which there are object data and object array data)** using jQuery/javascript which data is from the ajax response. And here, I give an example of JSON data

```js
{
  "peserta": {
    "id_peserta": "9",
    "user": "14",
    "event": "1",
    "kontingen": "18",
    "gender": "pa",
    "usia_kategori": "1",
    "kategori": "1",
    "video": "1615912156_5cdaea8b0938db3bdd94.mp4",
    "created_at": "2021-03-16 23:29:17.000000",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-16 23:29:17.000000",
    "status": "0",
    "slug_code": "70473488fc36724e8d0b"
  },
  "event": [
    {
    
      "id_event": "1",
      "nama": "M Jhon",
      "jenis_kelamin": "1",
      "tgl_lahir": "2010-06-16",
      "provinsi": "35",
      "kabupaten": "3519",
      "kecamatan": "351912",
      "kelurahan": "3519122009",
      "alamat": "Indonesia",
      "no_hp": "087830052034",
      "pas_foto": "1615908880_511668fc47fcfda5b5cf.jpg",
      "ktp": "1615908880_45e7d016c879b4d97520.jpg",
      "created_at": "2021-03-16 22:34:40.000000",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-16 22:34:40.000000",
      "status": "1",
      "slug_code": "675dba8ef1f46805cc6a",
      "id_gallery": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you already know you want to use `forEach()` I'm not clear what the issue is? The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) have clear instructions and examples on its use. If you have a specific issue please post the code you tried within the question so that we can help you to debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) and then manipulate it

```
// You can have any JSON object, just an example
const json = '{"result":20, "result2":42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(key => {
    // using obj[key] you can access the value for each key  
    console.log(obj[key])
})
```